# How many coins does Satoshi have?

Tags: blockchain, satoshi-nakamoto

There are rumors that the creator of Bitcoin, [Satoshi Nakamoto](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_Nakamoto), currently possess as much as 1.5m bitcoins.

What are the steps involved to determine / guess how many coins Satoshi has?

Comment: Close not sure if it's a duplicate though. Asking which wallets belong to someone is a pretty different question and is impossible to answer I think this is a better wording and more likely for people to come across later.

Comment: @mschuett. it really isnt any different unless you want to argue semantics. the only reason to ask is to know how much someone premined. and as the answer in nate's linked question says, you can find out which wallet(s) are his in the same manner as you would his wealth. the only reason you're arguing differently is so that you can copy the answer in nate's linked question in a vain attempt at rep whoring.

Comment: @mschuett: If this is closed as a duplicate, it won't be deleted, it will just get a prominent link to the earlier question. It will still appear in searches, so people who try this wording would find it, and then be directed to the other question. The usual protocol on this site is to post all answers on the earliest question, so they are all together.

Comment: @mattburnett No intention of rep whoring. As you can see I barely post and could care less if i get some magic internet points. I did not know as Nate said the normal way to do this was to always link forward to the new one. Please don't make stack exchange a toxic environment for new and old users alike I see no benefit in driving away people.

Comment: Where's the link to the duplicate post?

Comment: It is above the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most people have estimated his wealth to be around 1 Million BTC. Don't take my word for it though this post https://bitslog.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/the-well-deserved-fortune-of-satoshi-nakamoto/ is often the first referring to this discussion.